# How to avoid MissingPropertyException

Tags: groovy

If an object does not have a property and I am accessing the property, we get a `MissingPropertyException`. Can I do something similar to safe null (`?.`) to guard against missing properties so it doesn't throw an exception?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One option would be:

```
def result = obj.hasProperty( 'b' ) ? obj.b : null
```

Which would return null if the object doesn't have the property...

Another would be to add `propertyMissing` to your class like so:

```
def propertyMissing( name ) {
  null
}
```

This means that any missing properties would just result in null.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use try/catch

```
try
{   env.GERRIT_TOPIC=GERRIT_TOPIC
}
catch (e_val)
{   echo 'missing GERRIT_TOPIC'
}
```