# Groovy throws MissingPropertyException when propertyMissing is defined to return null

Tags: jenkins, groovy

A particular `jenkinsfile` is being used by 2 different Jenkins job. Job1 needs to pass `PARAM1` and `PARAM2` to the job. This is done through the use of string parameters in the job configuration. job2 only needs to pass `PARAM1`. This is also done through a string parameter.

So job1 has 2 strings parameter, `PARAM1` and `PARAM2`.

job2 has 1 string parameter, `PARAM1`.

To avoid the use of `try { ... } catch (MissingPropertyException) { ... }`, I have tried to use [the workaround described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196817/how-to-avoid-missingpropertyexception). My code is as follows:

```
def propertyMissing(name) {
  println "*** something could not be resolved to a parameter - will be set to NULL ***"
}

PARAM1 = PARAM1 ?: 'default value'
PARAM2 = PARAM2 ?: 'default value'
```

On job2, this fails at `PARAM2 = PARAM2 ?: 'default value'` and throws an exception: `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: PARAM2 for class: groovy.lang.Binding`.

On job1, this fails at another stage when trying to set an environment variable (`env.SOMETHING = 'value') and I get the following stack trace:

```
*** env could not be resolved to a parameter - will be set to NULL ***
*** currentBuild could not be resolved to a parameter - will be set to NULL ***
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot set property 'result' on null object
```

Is there a way to avoid the use of try / catch statement in this scenario?